# How to make dynamic content change in infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a package called react-infinite-scroller (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller). I'm having header with dynamic topics if i click on any topic i need to show the data belongs to that topic. 
hasLoadMore() is a function in that package that will give the next page that i need to send API to get the next set of data. If I change the topic, hasLoadMore() function giving the page, not starting from 0 instead it gives me the page number where the page previously loaded.
How can I implement that.

```js
<InfiniteScroll
  pageStart={0}
  loadMore={this.getPaymentPendingInvoices}
  hasMore={this.state.hasMorePaymentPendingItems}
  loader={this.renderSkeletonLoader()}
  threshold={50}
>
  <>
    {data &&
    data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
    <div key={index}>
      <InvoiceCard
      invoice={item}
      showModal={this.showModal}
      closeModal={this.closeModal}
      />
    </div>
    );
    })}
  </>
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a state variable and set `pageStart` equal to that. Conditionally render that variable by using a boolean to check whether not you need it to start at zero.

```js
<InfiniteScroll
  pageStart={this.state.shouldStartAtZero ? 0 : this.state.pageStart}
  loadMore={this.getPaymentPendingInvoices}
  hasMore={this.state.hasMorePaymentPendingItems}
  loader={this.renderSkeletonLoader()}
  threshold={50}
>
```